# How to disable font smoothing in Visual Studio editor?

Tags: windows, fonts, visual-studio-2012

How can I disable the font smoothing in the text editor of Visual Studio? On some machines I use, this works, but, not in most of them.

[The text in the editor on the left is not really sharp. But the font in Windows is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYqUe.png)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have Cleartype disabled in Windows?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/visual-studio-2010-text-clarity-cleartype-and-aliased-fonts.aspx) on the Visual Studio website?

Comment: ClearType is disabled for the Windows windows but not for VS.  Strange.  You'll need to describe the hammer you used to disable it for Windows.

Comment: Your using Consolas in the code window, that font *always* renders using clear type, you will need to change to something else.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: Workaround: Use Lucida Console.

Comment: @AlexK. you are right that VS always seems to use smoothing for Consolas, but PuTTY renders Consolas without smoothing if asked, so it looks like some oversight in VS not to respect the global ClearType settings.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

For me it helped to switch to "Consolas" font and then back to "Courier New" in Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors. Don't forget to press "OK" after switching to Consolas.

Comment: Does not answer how to disable anti-aliasing in Visual Studio without disabling anti-aliasing system-wide.

Answer (score 16):

There is an extension called *Text Sharp* that allows you to completely disable font smoothing (ClearType) for Visual Studio:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7aafa2ea-8c54-4da8-922e-d26bf018514d

I'm using this combined with the [Source Code Pro](https://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFontPackage&code=1960) font for very readable code.

Well, the characters are at least readable. The code itself may be a different story. :)

Comment: +1 for differing the characters from the code :D using exactly the same plugin as Visual Studio seems to ignore Windows settings... This should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 13):

In Visual Studio 2019 v16.5.4 (possibly lower), there is a new feature under the Text Editor -> Advanced settings called "Text rendering method". This appears to be defaulted to "ClearType" upon installation. On my machine, I've disabled ClearType at the OS level, yet after a fresh install/update, noticed that my fonts were being smoothed.

Simply switch this setting to "Aliased" to get pixel-perfect font rendering back.

[image: Go to Text Editor - Advanced - Text Rendering Method]

[image: Change to Aliased to get pixel perfect rendering back]

Again, this assumes you have already disabled ClearType at the system level. I am unsure if VS settings would ignore/override the system-level ClearType settings or not.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that I had the text size to 120%, I just change it to 100%.

Is an option located in Display Settings above the Resolution selector. It says:
"Change the size of the text, apps, and other items"
set the value to:
100% (Recommended)

This happened to me when I added a new LCD monitor to my setup.

Answer (score 1):

According to [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/visual-studio-2010-text-clarity-cleartype-and-aliased-fonts.aspx) and [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/405066/what-are-all-the-places-where-cleartype-can-be-disabled), you may have to disable it in many places, but for VStudio two are enough:

- Control Panel > Display > Adjust ClearType Text
- Control Panel > System > Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows > Visual Effects > Smooth edges of screen fonts

Don't use `Consolas` as it always uses ClearType, as Alex K. noted in the comments.

Prefer `Lucida Console` which is a fixed font (they are bold in VStudio's font list in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors) and appears not to suffer from the effects of ClearType or smoothed edges.

Answer (score 0):

For those willing to disable anti-aliasing/smooth edges/cleartype on VS Code as of today, there's no official option inside the VS Code program to do it. Instead, I have found this method that works for me, and it's thanks to this article: https://medium.com/kasun-kodagoda/fix-text-becomes-blurry-when-vs-code-application-loses-focus-issue-on-windows-d95697b2f927

Here are the steps:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2i9S.png" alt="..." />
```

Disable anti-aliasing VSCode Image:

[image: Disable anti-aliasing VSCode Image]

1. Right click on VS Code program and go to Proprieties.
2. In the "target" section of the app, add the following lines: `--disable-gpu --enable-use-zoom-for-dsf`
3. Apply the changes and that's it.

I hope it's useful.